# C# Trying to GET Data with the same ID but multiple orders

Tags: c#, datareader

Good Evening,

I'm having trouble with the following code, it works but it only shows one single order from one ID:

```cs
namespace ProjectDatabase.Models
{
    public class searchQuery
    {
        public AppDb Db { get; }

        public searchQuery(AppDb db)
        {
            Db = db;
        }

        public async Task<search> FindAllAsync(int id)
        {
            using var cmd = Db.Connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"...My Query";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@id_customer",
                DbType = DbType.Int32,
                Value = id,
            });
            var result = await ReadAllAsync(await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync());
            return result.Count > 0 ? result[0] : null;
        }

        public async Task<search> FindOneIdAsync(int id)
        {
            using var cmd = Db.Connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"...My Query";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@id_customer",
                DbType = DbType.Int32,
                Value = id,
            });
            var result = await ReadAllAsync(await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync());
            return result.Count > 0 ? result[0] : null;
        }

       
        public async Task<List<search>> LatestSearchAsync()
        {
            using var cmd = Db.Connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"... My Query";
            return await ReadAllAsync(await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync());
        }

        private async Task<List<search>> ReadAllAsync(DbDataReader reader)
        {
            var adb_search = new List<search>();
            using (reader)
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    var search = new search(Db)
                    {
                        id_customer = reader.GetInt32(0),
                        delivery_person_name = reader.GetString(1),
                        firstname = reader.GetString(2),
                        lastname = reader.GetString(3),
                        email = reader.GetString(4),
                        order_number = reader.GetString(5),
                    };
                    adb_search.Add(search);
                }
            }
            return adb_search;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what it will be shown in Postman:

```js
{
    "id_customer": 88,
    "delivery_person_name": "Name",
    "firstname": "firstname",
    "lastname": "lastname",
    "email": "email",
    "order_number": "order"
}
```

The problem is that this customer with the ID 88 for example will have a lot more orders done, like 50 but it specifically only shows me the first order and that's it. Its over, the other 49 orders will not be shown.

Its weird because i have another query within those 3 thats made to show me all Users in the Database and it works fine and shows me all 100 users, but with the orders query it only show me 1 result and thats it.

Maybe the problem is that I am using the same result to show 2 different queries ? And before you ask, yes I have tested the query in SQLyog and it shows me the 50 orders, but in the code it only shows me the first order.

Before you judge, yes I am a noob at C#.

Thanks, NewSounD.

Comment: Doesn't this explain it: `return result.Count > 0 ? result[0] : null;`? You are only returning the first item of the enumerable. Shouldn't it be `return result.Count > 0 ? result : null;`?

Comment: Hello, I have already tried to do that but it gives me the following error: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ProjectDatabase.Models.search>' to 'ProjectDatabase.Models.search'

Comment: Hello. `await ReadAllAsync(await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync());` return `List<search>`. Your method return `search`. Fix it and replace `return result.Count > 0 ? result[0] : null;` with `return result;`.

Comment: @NewSounD Your method signature is wrong, change from `public async Task<search> FindAllAsync(int id)` to `public async Task<List<search>> FindAllAsync(int id)`

Comment: @RyanWilson OMG, it worked !! Thank you very much! So with List it essentially builds a List before executing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `FindAllAsync` return `Task<search>`. You want a list, so you need to return `Task<List<search>>`.

This force you to return only one **search** and write this code: `return result.Count > 0 ? result[0] : null;`.

## Fixed code:

```cs
public async Task<List<search>> FindAllAsync(int id)
{
    using var cmd = Db.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = @"...My Query";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "@id_customer",
        DbType = DbType.Int32,
        Value = id,
    });
    var result = await ReadAllAsync(await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you and Ryan Wilson, I also used return result.Count > 0 ? result : null; instead of just return result.